# Printing silently from Spring MVC/Jasper Application

Tags: spring-mvc, printing, jasper-reports

This is very abstract question.

I'm working on a Spring MVC Web Application which has to deal with lot of invoice printing continuously. Currently When the invoice is saved, the spring controller delegates the invoice id to the  jasper pdf generation service which prepares the pdf. After the pdf gets downloaded, the user manually prints it.

I need a way to print the invoice silently when the user saves the invoice.

Any ideas?

Comment: You mean when the user saves it on their end you want it to print to a printer on your end?

Comment: *print to a printer on their end, to an attached printer on the user's workstation

Answer (score 0):

Since you are exporting to PDF it is possible. You need to add a `JRPdfExporterParameter.PDF_JAVASCRIPT` parameter to your `JRPdfExporter` instance with the value `"this.print({bUI: true,bSilent: false,bShrinkToFit: true});"`. For Example:

```
protected static byte[] exportReportToPdf(JasperPrint jasperPrint) throws JRException{
    JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();       
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, baos);
    exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.PDF_JAVASCRIPT, "this.print({bUI: true,bSilent: false,bShrinkToFit: true});");     
    exporter.exportReport();        
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

This actually adds the JavaScript to the PDF. When the PDF is opened it is ran, and will send it the print queue. It should be noted that this should be used sparingly as it is not generally considered to be nice to do this automatically for your users. When I have used it in an app, we had to buttons for each report. An `Export` button, that does not contain the JavaScript, and a `Print` button that did. That way users that wanted it to just print it would do so, and those that wanted a digital copy had that also.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313165/jasper-pdf-export-printing-in-internet-explorer jschoen - I was wondering if you could look at my question, it is similar to the situation in this question, and you have a lot of insight.  I'm having trouble around the embedded print javascdript not working consistently cross browsers.