# PDF export printing in Internet Explorer

Tags: java, javascript, pdf, browser, jasper-reports

```
protected static byte[] exportReportToPdf(JasperPrint jasperPrint) 
                                                      throws JRException {
  JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();       
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

  exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
  exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, baos);
  exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.PDF_JAVASCRIPT, 
              "this.print({bUI: true,bSilent: false,bShrinkToFit: true});");

  exporter.exportReport();        
  return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

We are using code like this to export a PDF document from a Jasper application.

The line

```
exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.PDF_JAVASCRIPT, 
             "this.print({bUI: true,bSilent: false,bShrinkToFit: true});");
```

adds JavaScript to send the PDF document directly to the printer.

The expected behavior is that a print dialog will come up with a preview of the PDF document.

This works fine most of the time - except I am having problems about one out of every 5-6 times in Internet Explorer 8 and Firefox.

What happens is - the print preview dialog with the PDF document does not appear or it appears with a blank document in the preview window.

-I've tried a number of different JavaScripts (different params to `this.print()` via `exporter.setParameter`
-I've tried setting different response headers such as

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition","inline;  filename=\"" 
                   + reportName 
                   + "\"");
response.setContentLength(baos.size());
```

these did not seem to help

This seems to be an IE and FF issue.  Has anyone ever dealt with this problem?  I need to get it to work across all browsers 100% of the time.  Perhaps a different approach to accomplish the goal of sending the PDF document export directly to the printer?  or a third party library that will work across browsers?

Comment: Could you read that document in the Acrobat?

Comment: Yes, if we comment out exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.PDF_JAVASCRIPT, 
              "this.print({bUI: true,bSilent: false,bShrinkToFit: true});"); then we are able to download the file as a pdf attachment.  This works fine in all browsers.

Comment: What is this rif software?  Does it work with jasper reports or is it a substitute for jasper?

Comment: Still experiencing this problem, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: @RomanC: Please stop italicizing API/library/framework/product names in suggested edits. This is not normal English and reads very disturbing. Capitalizing them is good, but italicizing them makes no utter sense.

Comment: Just a guess, but since it is sporadic it means one of two things: 1) the server is sending something different every 5 or 6 times and Chrome (I assume it works since not mentioned) works because it ignores whatever is changed or 2) FF and IE8 are doing something weird with how it is caching it. I have no idea which, but if it is caching it, maybe there is a header you can set to tell it to never do that. You could use something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to view the response headers. Good luck.

Comment: I actually use fiddler and I can see the raw response data has come through in all cases - as in I see the response is the right size and has an END OF FILE.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it isn't getting a chance to update the UI.  The following code delays the print perhaps giving it the chance it needs.  I didn't test as I don't have your environment.

```
exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.PDF_JAVASCRIPT,
    "app.setTimeOut('this.print({bUI: true,bSilent: false,bShrinkToFit: true});',200);")
```

Comment: But isn't this javascript purely for the pdf?  I don't think the PDF_JAVASCRIPT is adding anything to the dom?

Comment: @user619804, the JS isn't adding anything to the DOM, sure, but you have no idea about what race conditions may exist between the browser (who controls rendering and printing) and the Adobe plugin. Did you try Mike's suggestion? Did it make any difference at all?

Comment: Try increasing the timeout value