# printing pdf embed/iframe IE8+

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe

I have an iframe with a pdf embedded in an iframe body, I'd like to focus on the iframe and print its contents.  The iframe is visibility:hidden with height and width of 1px.

```
                    window.frames["iframeId"].focus();
                    window.frames["iframeId"].print();
```

this doesn't seem to be working in IE8.  What happens is I'm presented with a print dialog - but what is printed is not what I'm expecting - it's trying to print the entire browser window instead of the contents of the iframe.  Seems like focus() is not working in IE?  Is there any way around this issue?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The browser cannot print a PDF in this way. The code to print a PDF comes from WITHIN the plug-in, not the browser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313165/jasper-pdf-export-printing-in-internet-explorer - I posted another question about this.  I actually tried embedding a print function within the pdf using jasper jrpdfexporter.  This approach seems to work in all browsers except IE8 - the problem is the IE print dialog does not appear sometimes, it appears intermittent.  Since I was having so many problems with this approach, I tried printing the iframe contents from the parent page.

Comment: Any idea why the javascript added to the pdf via jasper jrpdfexporter does not work in IE?